# Cross-classified mixed models in lme4: How to code cluster variables when there are >2 random intercepts?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data, crossed-random-effects

Let's suppose that I have a dataset where individual responses to a questionnaire are cross-classified within two grouping variables, G1 and G2.

Based on [this very informative post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified), it seems that cross-classified models cannot be tested in lme4 if the G1 labels are all uniquely coded (e.g., if there are 10 different groups and they are coded 1-10). Regardless of lme4 syntax for nested vs. crossed, uniquely coded G1 labels will produce the output of a nested model.

On the other hand, a crossed model output can be obtained if the proper syntax is used [(1 | G1) + (1 | G2)] AND the G1 labels are symmetrical across the different values of G2 (e.g., 1-5 for G2=0; 1-5 for G2=1).

What about the situation when a cross-classified model is desired, but there are 3 or more grouping variables? How is it possible to have the G1 labels be symmetrical/non-unique across all values of G2 and G3 at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the corresponding section for [nested versus crossed random effects in the GLMM-FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed). In the manner **lme4** is programmed it is best practice to code the nested levels uniquely. In this manner, the corresponding model-fitting functions in the package will work correctly either you have a nested or crossed design.